# Why is my screen going black when I press F11?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

For the past week, when I'm playing and go into full screen mode (by pressing F11), instead of taking 3-4 seconds for the display to refresh and show Minecraft again, the screen goes black and stays like that. I tried restarting my Minecraft 5 times and haven't had any success.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Could you provide us with any more information? Are you using mods or playing on a server?

Comment: Umm im using the normal mc mods for pvp like the status huds bspkrs core reis minimap a hidden ghost client in toggle sneak with trigger bot xray and knockback and also kohi tcp no delay mod and timechanger mod and keystrokes mod which show your key presses and liteloader with a gamma bright mod and tabbychat

Comment: Ive tried to use normal mc also still same error black screen for 3-4 seconds when full screening and yah

Comment: Same with vanilla Forge

Comment: Was that problem before?  OR it just started after installing mods?

Comment: No it started after i reset my .minecraft since the client i had i unbinded the right shift gui accidently and deleted my configs but after that it was fine but i didnt play for 2 days on my pc but played on my mac so after that whenever i fullscreen its blacked out i need fast fullscreen to check the time or something like check the recording

Comment: help anyone? i need someone to help me fix this its annyoning to not be able to check the time while im playing / pvpin and i die because of the black screen

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because (according to the comments) it is asking for technical support for a heavily-modded Minecraft and possibly unofficial clients.

Comment: OP said he tried to use normal mine craft and he never mentioned an unofficial client.

Comment: @BleedingCatz Look at the first comment: `Umm im using the normal mc mods for pvp like the status huds bspkrs core reis minimap a hidden ghost client in toggle sneak with trigger bot xray and knockback and also kohi tcp no delay mod and timechanger mod and keystrokes mod which show your key presses and liteloader with a gamma bright mod and tabbychat ` Sounds very much modded.